# Get login shell as root `su -l` without changing directory

Tags: shell, su

Is there a way to run something like `su -l` that reads all the login shell files but doesn't change the directory that you're in?

For some motivation, I'm trying to create a Slackware Linux package. Most of the time packages will build correctly if you just use `su`. However, there are some packages like `sbcl` that depend on `TeX` tools and will fail without `su -l`. I prefer using `su` when I can get away with it because it doesn't change the current directory.

If I'm in a directory like `~/opt/haskell-stack-slackbuild`.

```
$ pwd
/home/<user>/opt/haskell-stack-slackbuild
```

If I just run `su` I'm back in the same directory, but if I run `su -l` then I get dropped in `/root` regardless of where I was and have to navigate back to the directory I was working in.

```
$ su -l
# pwd
/root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just source root's `.profile` after you are running in the root shell?

```
$ su
Password: 
# . ~root/.profile
#
```

Of course you can source any script from anywhere once in the root shell, and thus fix or change the root shell environment in any way that is necessary.

There are many ways one could inject different settings into the root shell directly from the origin shell using the fact that `su` accepts "shell parameters" on its command line.   Here's an example that gives the `su` command the instructions to run the root shell in such a manner as to source root's profile and then start a shell with the environment from that profile (which, because of the `exec`, replaces the shell started by `su`):

```
$ su -- root -c ". /root/.profile; exec /bin/sh" 
Password: 
#
```

Comment: oh interesting. Is there a way to do that as one command so I can hide it behind an alias?

Comment: I think I found a better one. `su -- root -c "exec /bin/bash -l"`. (I think my default shell is specifically not bash not sh which happens to point to bash) Keeps me in the same directory, but sources `/etc/profile` or `/root/.profile` or others as appropriate.

Comment: as I said, there are many ways!  :-)